# Write a function using recursion or higher order functions

Tags: haskell

How to write a function that takes a predicate `f` and a list `xx` and reutrns true if `fx` is true for some `x∈xs`?

For example:

```
 ghci>exists (>2) [1,2,3]
     True
```

This is the function I wrote:

```
 exists :: (t->Bool)->[t]->Bool
    exists f a []=error
    exists f a (x:xs)
                |if x∈f a  =True
                |otherwise= x:f a xs
```

I know this is not right, but I don't know why. Do I need to write this predicate function `f` first, then used it inside the function `exists`. Because I really don't know how to compare one element of list `xs` with the function.

Comment: Note that `(x::xs)` is a typo. It should be `(x:xs)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we take a look at your definition,

```
exists :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
exists f a []=error
exists f a (x:xs)
            |if x∈f a  =True
            |otherwise= x:f a xs
```

We see that your type is

```
exists :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
```

So `exists` must take two parameters, one predicate function of type `(t -> Bool)` and one list of type `[t]`. It returns a `Bool`. This seem okay as per our intention of the specification.

Let us look at the first line of your terms:

```
exists f a [] = error
```

This function suddenly takes three parameters. The `f` and the empty list constructor `[]` looks okay, but the `a` is not mentioned in the type specification. Hence, we prune it out:

```
exists f [] = error
```

Now, the `error` returned is not of boolean value. But the spec says it must be. Let us suppose we are asking `exists (<2) []`. Then would a natural answer to the question be `True` or `False`? Or paraphrased, is there any element `x in []` satisfying the predicate `f x` ?

On to the next line,

```
exists f a (x:xs)
      |if x∈f a  =True
      |otherwise= x:f a xs
```

We learned that the `a` has to go by the type specification, so let us prune it. Since we have now grown a natural dislike for the `a`, why not prune it everywhere it occur. Also, since the `if` will produce a syntax error, lets rid ourselves of that too:

```
exists f (x:xs)
      | x∈f    = True
      | otherwise = x:f xs
```

The `x∈f` does not make much sense, but `f x` does. The guard variant will be taken if `f x` returns true. Now, the True which is returned here sounds about right. It signifies that we have found an element in the list matching the predicate - and lo n' behold, `x` might be it!

So we turn our attention to the final line. The `otherwise` means that the guard `f x` did not return True. As a consequence, the `x` is not satisfying the predicate, so we must search the rest of the list.

The Right-hand-side `x : f xs` is peculiar. The `:` means that we will try to return a list, but the return type of the function is something of type `Bool`. The type checker won't like us if we try this. Furthermore, we have no reason to look at the `x` anymore since we just determined it does not satisfy the predicate.

The key thing you are missing is that we need *recursion* at this point. We need to search the tail `xs` of the list somehow - and recursion means to invoke the `exists` function on the tail.

Your general track is right, but ask again if something is unclear. One trick might be to go by the types for the recursion case: "What do i have to supply `exists` for it to return a `Bool` value?".

Comment: Dan caught that the :: operator is :, fixed.

Answer (score 15):

Your desired example usage is this

```
ghci>exists (>2) [1,2,3]
True
```

Stop. Hoogle time. ( <------ This should be the Haskell motto imho)

You want a function ("exists") that takes two parameters. The first is a unary function `(a -> Bool)` and the second is a list `[a]`. The desired result is a `Bool`

[Hoogling that type signature](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+Bool)+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+Bool), `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`, the top hits are `any`, `all`, and `find`. As Andrew has noted, `any` is the one that behaves like the "exists" function.

As a side note, my first thought was to use `find`, which returns a `Maybe a`, and then pattern match. If it returns `Nothing`, then the result would be `False`, otherwise `True`.

As another side note, the [actual implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#any) is simply `any p = or . map p`.

The third side note is probably the answer to your actual question. How is `map` defined? Hoogle is once again your friend. Search for the method's name and you can find a page that links to the source. I suggest you do this for `map` and `or`, but will only show `map` here.

```
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

That's the basic way to recurse over a list. `recursiveCall f (x:xs) = f x : recursiveCall f xs` But if it can be written with `map`, `filter`, or `foldl`/`foldr`, then you should do it with these recursive methods. (Stop. Hoogle time. Search for those method names and check out the source; it's pretty straightforward.)

Comment: I like the answer, even though it might be over the head of the questioner. The cool thing is that you can now come back to the this question and learn something new as your skill level improves.

Comment: +1 for a great answer and "Stop. Hoogle time." Made my morning :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think the function you want already exists -- `any`:

```
Prelude> :t any
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
Prelude> any (<3) [1, 2, 3, 4]
True
Prelude> any (<3) [3, 4, 5, 6]
False
```

And then, in the spirit of your question -- not just getting a working function but working out how it's done -- we can look up the definition in the prelude:

```
any p xs = or (map p xs)
```

We `map` the function over the list to get a new `[Bool]` list, and then check with `or` to see if any of them are `True`, which by the way thanks to lazy evaluation short circuits as needed:

```
Prelude> any (<3) [1, 2..]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your original version wasn't too far from working. To fix it, write:

```
exists :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
exists _ [] = False
exists f (x:xs)
            | f x = True
            | otherwise = exists f xs
```

Comment: Alternately, exists f (x:xs)    = f x || exists f xs . See http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#any

Comment: Yes, that's much nicer, but the point was to get the original code "working".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `x` in `f`, just apply `f` to `x` using `f x` as the predicate in the if statement.  Your `otherwise` clause should also return a `Bool`: the result of `exists` on the rest of the list.